# Coloring substrings in an HTML multiple select option

Tags: html, select, colors

I have a multiple select box that is populated with a set of options that contain a substring that a user enters as a keyword in a search. The user can then select what they want from the generated select box.

To make things easier, I would like to highlight the substring in each of the options in the select box.

Is this possible, and, if so, how would it be accomplished?

Comment: Might be possible with JavaScript, but I've never seen that done before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to style the text inside a select box. You would have to write your own select box with javascript.